# Copy nearest select box value of a given class name to following select box of same class name (using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is:

On the HTML sample below, when a user clicks "Copy from above", I want the jQuery to search 'up' the HTML structure from the click location, find the previous select box with `class="colors"`, copy the selected value ***FROM*** that select box and use it to select the same value in the select box immediately below it (also with `class="colors"`). Every select box has the same set of values.

Sample HTML:

```
<select class="colors">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
```

I have tried various combinations of `.prevAll()`, but I can't get it working.

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: *copy the selected value FROM that select box TO the select box immediately below it* When the value is copied, how did you want that value stored...To the select box isn't very explanatory. Did you want the new value added TO the select box as an extra `<option>`? or change the value of an `<option>` to that of the new value? If so...which `<option>`?

Comment: zer00ne.. change the value.

Comment: Change the value of the first one, second one, third one, all of them, or whatever position the original one is in change the same one, but that would be pointless because it wouldn't change then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was pointless at first, but now that I see it in action, I see there's a use for this behavior. Thanks for your patience in explaining it.

This seems pretty basic nothing fancy.

- Delegate the click event on all occurrences of `.copy-times`
- Prevent `.copy-times` from jumping like an `<a>`nchor
- Use variable `above` (`var above`) to store `this` (`.copy-times`) previous sibling (`.prev()`) with class `.colors` (`select.colors`) value (`.val()`).
- Get `this` (`.copy-times`) next sibling (`.next()`) with the class `.colors` (`select.colors`) value (`.val()`) and set it to the value of the previous value (`above`).

#### SNIPPET

```js
$('.copy-times').on('click', function(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  var above = $(this).prev('.colors').val();
  $(this).next('.colors').val(above);
});
```

```css
select,
a {
  display: block;
}
select {
  margin: 0 0 20px 10px;
}
a {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2" selected>Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3" selected>Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This answer seems most robust. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you mean by copy - select the same value as the previous select, see the code below.

I went with adding `selected` attribute to the option with same `value` and removing it from other options.

```js
$(".copy-times").on("click", function(e){
  var $copyBtn = $(this);
 var copied = $copyBtn.prev(".colors").val();
  $copyBtn.next(".colors").children().each(function(i,e){
   var $option = $(this);
    if($option.val() == copied){
      console.log(this);
     $option.attr("selected", "");
    } else {
     $option.removeAttr("selected");
    }
  })
})
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors">
  <option value="1">Red</option>
  <option value="2">Blue</option>
  <option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes I should have said "select the same value". Your jsfiddle looks good, I'll confirm it when I get back to my desktop. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

@Callum Can you please have a look at this code if this will meet your requirement

Let me know if there any changes to be done.

```js
function getSelected(src,target){ 
 $( "#"+target ).val($( "#"+src ).val());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="colors" id="first">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>

<a href="#" class="copy-times"  onclick="getSelected('first','second')">Copy from above</a>
<select class="colors" id="second">
<option value="1">Red</option>
<option value="2">Blue</option>
<option value="3">Green</option>
</select>
```